# iMacro script crashes when the wrong page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, imacros

I wrote an iMacro script to horde AddMeFast points and it is crashing my browser when it hits a page with an error. Is there any way to make it stop crashing? I believe it has to do with the `TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Follow` not finding the Follow button on the page

Heres the script:

```
﻿VERSION BUILD=8940826 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://addmefast.com/free_points/twitter
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Follow
TAB T=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:follow_btn_form ATTR=TXT:Follow
TAB CLOSE
TAB T=1
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TAB CLOSE
```

This code crashes the FireFox if there is only one tab.